# Increase space between rows on FacetGrid plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, facet-grid

I've the following code which creates the plot you can see in the picture:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data, col="Provincia",col_wrap=6,size=2.5)
g.map(sns.barplot, "Anio", "Diff");
g.set_axis_labels("Año", "Porcentaje de aumento");

for ax in g.axes.flat:
    _ = plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible=True)
    _ = plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
    _ = plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels()[0], visible=True)    
    _ = plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels()[-1], visible=True)
```

The problem, as you can see in the picture, is that the x ticks collapse with the col name below. What is the proper way to increase this space in order to fix this?

[image: output]

Comment: As per [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html), it's better to directly use [figure-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) functions like [`g = sns.catplot(data=data, kind='bar', ...)`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) instead of `sns.FacetGrid`. The answers still work for this.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

#### tight layout

You can use [`tight_layout`](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html) to automatically adjust the spacings

```
g.fig.tight_layout()
```

or, if you have `matplotlib.pyplot` imported as `plt`,

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

#### subplots adjust

You can use `plt.subplots_adjust` to manually set the spacings between subplots,

```
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4, wspace=0.4)
```

where `hspace` is the space in height, and `wspace` is the space width direction.

#### gridspec keyword arguments

You could also use `gridspec_kws` in the `FacetGrid` initialization,

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data, ... , gridspec_kws={"wspace":0.4})
```

However, this can only be used if `col_wrap` is not set. (So it might not be an option in the particular case from the question).