# title and labels in seaborn are on the border

Tags: python, seaborn

I am doing a simple displot with seaborn

However when I do

```
ax2=sns.displot(outlist)
ax2.set(xlabel='Rate(Hz)', title='Distribution of publication rates')
```

I got

[image: problem]

How can I put the title and labels correctly?

Comment: My comments are supported, as per [FacetGrid change titles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43920341/7758804) & [FacetGrid change xlabels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36573789/7758804) & [Increase space between rows on FacetGrid plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43669229/7758804). However, it seems to depend whether there's a single, or multiple Facets.

Comment: But there are quite a number of ways to do each thing. See this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43920341/facetgrid-change-titles#comment74876614_43920664), and the response at the bottom of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43920664/7758804)

Comment: That said, @mwaskom is the developer of seaborn, so defer to his advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tight_layout`:

```
g = sns.displot(outlist)
g.set(xlabel='Rate(Hz)', title='Distribution of publication rates')
g.tight_layout()
```